# using fluentsecurity in modular system mvc 4

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization, fluent-security

I have an MVC application named `app_ui` in my solution as a startup project, and some other applications in solution as modules. Then in startup project I access to modules and their actions by routetable. I use `fluentsecurity` for authorization and configure it in `Global.asax` for controllers in `app_ui` and everything works perfectly. But for controllers and actions in modules I can not add config to fluentsecurity and want to know how to add set policy for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using **Profiles** in FluentSecurity 2.0 (beta1)! Here is a link to the documentation: https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/wiki/Profiles

**1) Create a profile in your module**

```
public class AdminAreaSecurityProfile : SecurityProfile
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        For<UserAdminController>().RequireRole(UserRole.Administrator)
        For<BlogAdminController>().RequireRole(UserRole.Editor)
    }
}
```

**2) Scan for profiles from the main application**

```
SecurityConfigurator.Configure(configuration =>
{
    configuration.GetAuthenticationStatusFrom(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);

    configuration.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
        scan.LookForProfiles();
    });
});
```

Comment: tanks for your answer. i enjoyed in this library. the problem that i had , was that modules assembly were not in Applicationbasedirectory so i use this code: scan.AssembliesFromPath(path, a => true);